# Can populating with $.each(..) "destroy" the ordering of my map in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, foreach

**My problem:**

I know it may sound funny, but here's my problem: I have a `select` that is populated through Ajax on success in the following way:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
            options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
        });
```

My server returns a **sorted map** (sorted by *value*). All works fine, **but** in Internet Explorer (7,8 and 9) the select appears unsorted.

**What I've found :**

What I've found is that IE actually displays it sorted by the `key` I am passing to the `value` parameter. My list is sorted on the back-end by `value`, and I want to display it like that (working fine on Chrome, Firefox, etc).

I am thinking that most probably the cause of this sorting is the `$.each` jQuery function. Maybe it is iterating by the key? I am not sure about this, though, so I would like some feedback. Also, how can I make an alternative iteration on the map, to make sure of this? I am trying to avoid to perform a jQuery sorting, as the sorting is done in the back-end.

I am mentioning that I need the `key` and `value` passed to the `option` the way that I am passing them.

**Edit - an example:**

How it should be (and is on Chrome and Firefox):

```
<option value="13">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="55">C</option>
```

How it is in IE:

```
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="13">A</option>
<option value="55">C</option>
```

Comment: Please don't create elements by appending HTML. jQuery has perfectly good DOM manipulation facilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that objects don't actually have a specific ordering of key/value pairs. IE is not wrong in changing it. Use an array to hold the pairs instead, something like:

```
[
    {
        "value": "13",
        "text": "A"
    },
    {
        "value": "2",
        "text": "B"
    },
    {
        "value": "55",
        "text": "C"
    }
]
```

And loop through it as follows:

```
$.each(data, function(index, option) {
    options += '<option value="' + option.value + '">' + option.text + '</option>';
});
```

Finally, you shouldn't manipulate HTML as a string to build elements. Use the DOM. I imagine you have `someElement.html(options);` somewhere? Well instead, make `options = someElement;`, and do this:

```
$.each(data, function(index, option) {
    options.append(
        $('<option>').prop('value', option.value).text(option.text)
    );
});
```

Comment: I have changed my server-side to create an array of pairs and passed it to the ajax call, and now it works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

minitech's is correct.

However nice it would be to assume the order will stay in an object, it is not guaranteed, and may break at any random time (or in IE, all the time).

Another solution, however, is to pass a sorted array that has the order you want to go through the keys.

```
[
  {
    13: 'A',
    2: 'B',
    55: 'C'
  },
  [ 13, 2, 55 ]
 ]
```